# Music + Video integration when using BackgroundAudioPlayer.Track/Play vs MediaHistoryItem.NowPlaying

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-player

According to the [`MediaHistory.NowPlaying`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.mediahistory.nowplaying%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) documentation:

> For applications using BackgroundAudioPlayer, there is no need to set the NowPlaying information because it is handled by the system automatically

Since [`AudioTrack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.audiotrack%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) does not contain an equivalent to [`MediaHistoryItem.PlayerContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.mediahistoryitem.playercontext%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), how can the application supply additional data so that it can correctly handle navigation from the Music + Video Hub or the Universal Volume Control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting a `NowPlaying` anyway and had it link to the "now playing" section of my app.

The *BackgroundAudioPlayer API* may not require you to set `NowPlaying`, but Music + Video integration does and it's the only way to provide other information (like `PlayerContext` data).